# How do I keep my elements on the same horizontal line?

Tags: html, css, block, display

I'm trying to get text and a link to remain on the same line.  I thought htis CSS would do the trick

```
#scenario-title {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

on the following HTML

```
<div id="scenario-title">
<h3>My Scenario</h3> ( <a class="name ellipsis" target="_blank" href="/scenarios/18">Download All</a> ) 
</div>
```

but nothing's that easy with HTML apparently.  Here's the Fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/92rv0Lpa/ .  How do I keep everything on the same horizontal line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving the div the display of inline-block, give it to the first tag (the h3 tag). Here is a working snippet:

```css
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  )
```

```html
<div id="scenario-title">
<h3>My Scenario</h3> ( <a class="name ellipsis" target="_blank" href="/scenarios/18">Download All</a> ) 
</div>
```

Matt

Comment: a correct answer just does fine, no need to add message :) **tag is h3, not h4 btw**

Comment: @GCyrillus Yeah, I just hate people that run with the answer without marking it as the correct answer or upvoting it :P

Comment: @MatthewBergwall - it happens once in a while; I agree it's frustrating. However, requests for upvotes or acceptance in answers is generally considered bad form here...

Comment: @Krease Thanks for telling me that, won't happen again.

Answer (score -1):

I have modified a little your code and this way I have achieved what you wanted, but if you want to learn more about how to develop layouts and improve your css positioning knowledge, study flexbox is very useful.

```css
#scenario-title {
    display: inline;
}
#scenario-title span, a
{
  display:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="scenario-title">
<span>My Scenario</span> <a class="name ellipsis" target="_blank" href="/scenarios/18">Download All</a> 
</div>
```

his game can help you understand flexbox [game flexbox](http://flexboxfroggy.com/)

Comment: display:relative; ?? did you mean display:perfect; ?